# mysql - How to concatenate strings and convert to date the strings?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

### Please take a look at my stored procedure code.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ninjaboy`@`%` PROCEDURE `getMonthlyTotalScore`(IN ninjaId int,  IN month int, IN year int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE startDate DATE;
    DECLARE endDate DATE;
    DECLARE maxDay INTEGER;

    SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(year + '-' + month + '-01')) INTO maxDay;

    SET startDate = year + '-' + month + '-01';
    SET endDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + maxDay;

    SELECT SUM(SCORE) FROM NINJA_ACTIVITY WHERE NINJA_ID = ninjaId AND DATE BETWEEN startDate AND endDate ORDER BY DATE;
END
```

### Test Data:

```
NINJA_ACTIVITY_ID | NINJA_ID | SCORE | DATE
1                   1          24      2012-05-01
2                   1          36      2012-05-06
3                   1          29      2012-05-11
```

Function call : `call getTotalMonthlyScore (1, 5, 2012)`

I'm trying to get the monthly score of any ninja based on the `ninjaId`.

Why is not working? Any idea where I am getting wrong?

Comment: Human mind is not a complier. What error did you get?

Comment: @beck03076 I didn't get any error. It only returns 0 (result);

Comment: So how can you be so sure the problem lies in the date handling? We can't tell for sure, since you don't provide sample data.

Comment: @Romain: Thanks. Ninjaboy: Your test data

Comment: Wait a min, what are you returning, Where is your out variable?. I think you should write a stored function.

Comment: @beck03076: The resultset of the `SELECT` will be returned to the client...

Comment: I really had hard time formatting the test data.

Comment: what does your "SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(year + '-' + month + '-01')) INTO maxDay;
"

return?

Comment: @eggyal: I realised that

Comment: @NinjaBoy: Sorted for you (you simply needed to wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tags).

Comment: @eggyal Thanks for fixing the format.

Comment: thats what I am telling, the argument of the last day is of type DATETIME eg, LAST_DAY(DATETIME), but you are not passing it and the max_date gets the null value and the between clause fails....

Comment: @beck03076 Oh I almost forgot because I was so relieved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**CONCAT() is the key.**

### BEFORE:

```
mysql> CREATE  PROCEDURE `getMonthlyTotalScore`(IN ninjaId int,  IN month int, IN year int)
        -> BEGIN
        ->     DECLARE startDate DATE;
        ->     DECLARE endDate DATE;
        ->     DECLARE maxDay INTEGER;
        -> 
        ->     SELECT year + '-' + month + '-01'; #NOTE THIS
        -> 
        ->     
        -> END;    
        -> |
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

    mysql> call getMonthlyTotalScore(1,5,2012);
        -> |
    +----------------------------+
    | year + '-' + month + '-01' |
    +----------------------------+
    |                       2016 |
    +----------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### AFTER:

```
mysql> CREATE  PROCEDURE `getMonthlyTotalScore`(IN ninjaId int,  IN month int, IN year int)
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE startDate DATE;
    ->     DECLARE endDate DATE;
    ->     DECLARE maxDay INTEGER;
    -> 
    ->     SELECT CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-01'); # NOTE THIS
    -> 
    ->     
    -> END;    |
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> call getMonthlyTotalScore(1,5,2012);
    -> |
+------------------------------+
| CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-01') |
+------------------------------+
| 2012-5-01                    |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @johntotetwoo Actually, they did. It possibly lacks an explanation that MySQL does LTR evaluation, and since the left operand is an `Int`, it'll transparently cast all subsequent operants to `Int` as well... hence the issue in the OP.

Comment: yeah i get it, i'm sorry. The OP lacks info.

Comment: @Romain: What is OP? and It is clear that CONCAT() was not used and instead, "a"+"b" is used. Please forgive my brains. It is a little stupid most times. What are you guys discussing about?

Comment: OP => Original Post. John says you don't answer the question, I say you do, since the issue is left-to-right evaluation of `+` in Integer context.

Comment: @Romain: I owe you one. Thanks for that. Take my phone number, call me when you can. "9999999999999". Hahaha. Mustnt do that around here right?. Otherwise why even we be here, goto spacebook, myface or whatever. Just kidding. Thanks for information again!

Comment: @beck03076 Thanks so much for your answer it really helped solve the problem. BTW, Im gonna post my working solution based from your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(year + '-' + month + '-01')) INTO maxDay;
```

replace it with

```
SET maxDay := DAY(LAST_DAY(CAST(CONCAT(year, '-',month,'-01) as DateTime)));
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting the idea from beck's answer I have this working solution.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ninjaboy`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getMonthlyTotalScore`(IN ninjaId int,  IN month int, IN year int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE startDate DATE;
    DECLARE endDate DATE;
    DECLARE maxDay INTEGER;

    SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-01'))) INTO maxDay;

    SET startDate =  CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-01');
    SET endDate = CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',maxDay);

    SELECT SUM(SCORE) FROM NINJA_ACTIVITY WHERE NINJA_ID = ninjaId AND DATE BETWEEN startDate AND endDate ORDER BY DATE;
END
```