# MySQL Stored Procedure Parameter IN and OUT

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to MySQL stored procedures and for the beginning purposes i created this little procedure. Simply take an input, concatinate "Hi! " with it and assign to OUT p2. What I am doing wrong?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testing`(IN `p1` CHAR(50), OUT `p2` TEXT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'this is comment'
BEGIN

set p2 = "Hi! " + p1;

END
```

When I call procedure using

```
CALL `testing`('Joe', @p);
select @p;
```

It gives me warning

```
Truncated incorrect double value: 'Hi!'
Truncated incorrect double value: 'Joe'
```

Any help for a beginner will be appreciated.

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680961/mysql-how-to-concatenate-strings-and-convert-to-date-the-strings

Comment: instead of "Hi! " + p1 use CONCAT("Hi!",p1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write procedure like this

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testing`(IN `p1` CHAR(50), OUT `p2` TEXT)
        LANGUAGE SQL
        NOT DETERMINISTIC
        CONTAINS SQL
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
        COMMENT 'this is comment'
    BEGIN

    set p2 = CONCAT("Hi! " , p1);

    END
```

Comment: Thanks but why "+" did not worked though it is used for concatenation in MySQL stored procedure. Will give me your time to explain it.

Comment: it is concat two string in javascript and other language but mysql does not supper + sign to concatation two string

Comment: Thanks ... I re read the last article where they told about concatenation and yes I was wrong they used "+" to explain wrong way to concatenation and later after few lines whoa i found CONCAT ... silly I am :p